# After updating Entity Framework model, every mapping data is deleted

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I have reopened an old project that uses entity framework and model generation, but when I update the model, all the mapping is deleted.

I have to add a new table to the model, but with this problem I can not do anything.
After adding the table, I have an error about the missing mapping :

"Error  113 Error 3027: No mapping specified for the following EntitySet/AssociationSet - Table1, Table2 [...]"

Anyone has had this problem?

For information, I use .NET 4.0, EF 6.1.3, Mysql connector 6.9.7.

Comment: Is the old project EF 6.1.3?

Comment: In EF6 for sure, but don't know if it was in EF 6.1.3 exactly. Same thing with MySQL Connector

Comment: it is general problem when you updating a model, now you have to delete and bind it again...no other option

Comment: it's sad, because I defined every relation by hand on this model

Comment: this is a biggest disadvantage of EF model

Comment: I've seen issues like this disappear if you just close and reopen the edmx.